# Opening a pdf and printing is not working using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print a PDF manually.
I tried the iframes way, but showing me cross-origin issues. To resolve this I tried:

```js
function printIframe(url) {
  var proxyIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.appendChild(proxyIframe);
  proxyIframe.style.width = '100%';
  proxyIframe.style.height = '100%';
  proxyIframe.style.display = 'none';

  var contentWindow = proxyIframe.contentWindow;
  contentWindow.document.open();
  contentWindow.document.write('<iframe src="' + url + '" onload="print();" width="1000" height="1800" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">');
  contentWindow.document.close();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="printIframe('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf')">Print</button>
```

And the above code is opening a print window, but the content is empty.

The other method I tried is:

```html
<a href="javascript: w=window.open('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf'); w.print();" >PRINT</a>
```

This will open the page for me, but won't open the print dialog.

Please let me know any feasible solution that works here.

Thanks.

Comment: you can do liek this : `const myWindow = window.open(myurl, "_blank");` and then do `myWindow.onload = myWindow.print();` however you see this error `SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "onload" on cross-origin object` , if you enable CORS for your domain it should work

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<embed>
```

tag to embed a pdf inside a document

Create a HTML file and copy paste the below code, it worked well for me

```
   <head>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <embed
    type="application/pdf"
    src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
    id="pdfDocument"
    width="100%"
    height="100%" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function printDocument(documentId) {

        var doc = document.getElementById(documentId);

        //Wait until PDF is ready to print    
        if (typeof doc.print === 'undefined') {    
            setTimeout(function(){printDocument(documentId);}, 1000);
        } else {
            doc.print();
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("pdfDocument").onload = function(){ 
        printDocument("pdfDocument");
       }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @chans, Thanks ofr the reply, But `doc.print === "undefined"` is going infinitely. And if try just `doc.print()` directly, it is throwing and error `doc.print is not a function`.

Comment: I just refactored the above code by adding onload function, now it is working as expected. let me know, if this resolves your issue

Comment: Hey @chans, nope, it's still the same.

Comment: @Archana,create a html file name sample.html,  just copy paste the above code in sample.html and  open the file in browser. it is working as expected. It requires network connection to test it

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did. No luck.